# I've done lots of searching, but I can't figure it out. How can I run a single command at startup?

Tags: startup

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 and the command I'm trying to execute at every startup is

> xinput set-prop 14 285 1

Actually, it would be even better to run it at every login as it resets if I log out, but I don't log out very often so just running at startup would work fine. I've looked through a lot of previous questions, tried getting .service or rc.local to do it but they don't seem to work and I'm still pretty green, or rather I've forgotten nearly all of what I knew in highschool since I took a four year Ubuntu hiatus and only just came back.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us what you tried in rc.local. That should work as expected.

Comment: For starting scripts after login to environment you can use app [`gnome-session-properties`](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html), but I suppose it's not what you need.

Comment: I'm no expert on this, bu I suppose that you could add a `Startup Application` with a command something like `bash -c "xinput set-prop 14 285 1"`. Let the experts chime in...

Comment: I ran into this issue too, and I think you actually want to add it to `.xinitrc`, so it automatically runs when X starts (but before your wm starts)